# how can i get following output?

Tags: oracle10g

```
table = emp

SAL
------
8000
7000
6000
5000
10000
9000
4000
8000
7000
```

For the above table, write a SELECT statement to display the Largest and Second largest Sals.  Your output should be as below:-

```
          first     second
         -------    --------
           10000     9000
```

i  wrote following query but i got following output:

```
select sal from (select rownum first, sal from(select distinct sal from emp1       order by sal desc))where first <= 2;
```

output:

```
 SAL
----- 
10000  
9000
```

Comment: Welcome... hit CTRL-K after selecting your code to indent it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use the DENSE_RANK function; also, if you avoid the MIN/MAX you can get any arbitrary Nth values as required:

```
with q as (
  select sal, dr from (
    select distinct
           sal
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sal DESC) dr
    from   emp
  ) where dr in (1,2,10)
)
select (select sal from q where dr = 1) first
      ,(select sal from q where dr = 2) second
      ,(select sal from q where dr = 10) tenth
from dual;
```

The query (q) should be materialized so the multiple queries of it should not result in extra passes through the data.

Answer (score 1):

Then select the minimal and the maximal value from your own request, into two distinct columns.

```
with   i
as     ( select sal
           from ( select rownum first
                       , sal
                    from ( select distinct sal
                             from scott.emp
                            order by sal desc ) )
          where first <= 2 )
select min ( i.sal )
     , max ( i.sal )
  from i
 group by i.sal;
```